# Make eloquent custom relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 tables :

User

Country

Post

Cities

User belongs to Country and User also belongs to Post !

I wish to be able to find all users that have at least one post and exists in at least one country and city

Is it possible using only Eloquent relationships like described here ?
What about polymorphic relationship ?

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I don't think you need a polymorphic relation for that, you can have two relations, one for country and another one for city, polymorphic relations are a little overkill for your usecase. you could do : `User::whereHas('country')->whereHas('city')->whereHas('post')->get()`

Comment: Is it possible with nested like User::whereHas('country.post')->get()

Comment: Yeah i mixed up the relations, but same principle apply

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use a polymorphic relation for that.

I believe that you have a `post_id` and a `country_id` column in the `User` table.

Also I believe you have the following relationships in the `User` model:

```
  public function country()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
  }

  public function post()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
  }
```

After that you can easily make your condition using eloquent model:

```
User::whereHas('post')->whereHas('country')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is true and no need to using polymorphic relationship here.

Polymorphic relationship used when some models are related to one model for example consider **Post** and **Article** models. To allow for comments on each of these, we can decide to set up polymorphic relationship.